# Can i build a Master - Detail webpage in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a complete application in MS ACCESS which I am planning to re-do as a web application , (but searching for the right platform).
Google Apps Script has several advantages, however I need to confirm if it allows building a full-blown web app.
For example, 
Can i add a login security page when user first opens the web page ?
Can i building a Master - Detail web page using Google Apps ?
_
Finally, coming from a MS ACCESS background, which would be most suitable choice of database to migrate to so things will work with Google Apps Script ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can i add a login security page when user first opens the web page?

Yes, you can. You'd have to get the credentials from somewhere and, unless they come from LDAP which I'm pretty sure you can't connect to, you will be able to handle them

> Can i building a Master - Detail web page using Google Apps ?

Not sure what that is, but if you mean a complex HTML page then yes, you can.

> Finally, coming from a MS ACCESS background, which would be most suitable choice of database to migrate to so things will work with Google Apps Script ?

This depends on how many queries you have to make, and how quickly you want them handled.

- If it's small, you can use [SpreadsheetApp itself](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).
- If it's bigger, you can use [BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery), [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/), or something else.
- And if it's even bigger, you will probably want to dive into Python, PHP, Java, or some other backend programming language.

Exporting tables from MS ACCESS and importing them into another DB software shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Lastly, who am I to answer this specific question? I come from a MS Access background myself, migrated over to Google Apps Script back when they had the `UiApp` and `ScriptDb` APIs, had a little bit of fun with `HtmlService` and I soon realized that for serious stuff, I need to have my own server, due to high latency between request/responses - so I started learning Python + Django.

These, in my opinion, are your options.